# WebDriver.findElement causing SocketExceptions for 10 seconds

Tags: selenium, webdriver, httpclient

I am having a strange issue with a suite of WebDriver test cases that is causing widespread failures.

One of the test cases in the suite is currently expected to fail - there is an open bug in the web site that is causing a tab to disappear. The test case that is supposed to click the tab calls the WebDriver's findElement method to look for the tab. It waits for the standard timeout, but then, instead of throwing the usual Exception and moving on, I start getting SocketExceptions in the console that aren't getting caught by the test case code that usually catches errors:

```
Apr 18, 2013 8:47:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
Apr 18, 2013 8:47:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect 
INFO: Retrying connect 
Apr 18, 2013 8:47:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect 
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect 
Apr 18, 2013 8:47:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect 
INFO: Retrying connect 
Apr 18, 2013 8:47:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect 
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect 
Apr 18, 2013 8:47:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect 
INFO: Retrying connect
```

The SocketExceptions cause an UnreachableBrowserException:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_32'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:493)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:502)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:372)
    at com.brainshark.uitests.common.TestBase.afterClass(TestBase.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:36)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at com.brainshark.uitests.runners.BrainsharkTestRunner.run(BrainsharkTestRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:297)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:357)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:472)
    ... 32 more
```

This causes each test case to fail fast, and for approximately 10 seconds, every attempt to run the next test case triggers the above failure. Then, something magical happens, and the Exceptions cease.

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this behavior? Or what takes 10 seconds to reset? Should I work around this by trying to detect situations like this and just hold still for 10 seconds before attempting to execute the next test case? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The SocketExceptions were being caused by making too many findElement calls in too short a period of time.

I have a customized find method which allows matching additional parameters like a text pattern in addition to the By locator. Under certain circumstances (namely, if there are elements that match the By locator but not the text pattern, such as in this case where there were multiple tabs, but the one with the text I was looking for was missing) this method can make repeated findElement calls for the duration of its timeout.

I never noticed the issue in development because I use a 20 second timeout when I'm writing tests, so they fail faster. In our actual runs, we use a 180 second timeout, which was enough time to overload Selenium with findElement calls.

I added some sleeps to ensure that I am only calling findElement every quarter of a second at most, and also put in a try/catch to trap the UnreachableBrowserException that will result if an overload still occurs. If it does, I just sleep for 40 seconds and try again. It seems to be working well now.

Comment: Probably related to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/webdriver/1xLNX06W6Cs/dmkOWAEBYlcJ) (explanation [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ScalingWebDriver) in case the link dies). A possible workaround, as I understand from the further link, could be using a Chrome driver instead of Firefox.

Comment: I have the same issue while using the Chrome driver on a windows machine. No errors on a mac. From an initial search it looks like a service pack issue on windows?